# XSD Conditional Grouping

Tags: xsd

I'm not entirely sure if I am using the correct process or even if it is possible, however what I want to do is create a XSL file that defines the following schema:

```
<data>
    <s>
        <name>Joe Blogs</name>
        <id>1235</id>
        <aa>data</aa>
        <ab>data</ab>
        <ad>data</ad>
        <ae>data</ae>
    </s>
    <s>
        <name>Jane Blogs</name>
        <id>1234</id>
        <ba>data</ba>
        <bb>data</bb>
    </s>
    <s>
        <name>Jane Blogs</name>
        <id>1234</id>
        <aa>data</aa>
        <ac>data</ac>
        <ad>data</ad>
        <ae>data</ae>
    <s>
</data>
```

So basically:

- The `<data>` tag is the root. It can be empty.
- The `<s>` tag can appear multiple times.

  - The `<ba>` tag must be acompanied by the tag `<bb>`.
  - The `<aa>` tag must be accompanied by the tags `<ad>` and `<ae>`.

    - The tag `<ab>` must only appear when `<aa>`(and associated tags) is present, but must not appear where `<ac>` and vica-verca.

I have tried to implement this with a  element:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="s" 
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                    minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name"/>
                <xs:element name="id"/>
                <xs:element name="aa"/>
                <xs:element name="ab"/>
                <xs:element name="ad"/>
                <xs:element name="ae"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name"/>
                <xs:element name="id"/>
                <xs:element name="aa"/>
                <xs:element name="ac"/>
                <xs:element name="ad"/>
                <xs:element name="ae"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name"/>
                <xs:element name="id"/>
                <xs:element name="ba"/>
                <xs:element name="bb"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  The problem is that given your current declaration, an XSD validator doesn't know, when it sees an initial `name` element which of the three sequences you've specified it should choose.  It's not allowed to look ahead in the input to make its choice; it has to be able to navigate the content model without lookahead.

Reformulating your complex type this way eliminates that problem.

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name"/>
    <xs:element name="id"/>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ba"/>
        <xs:element name="bb"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="aa"/>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="ab"/>
          <xs:element name="ac"/>                  
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="ad"/>
        <xs:element name="ae"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, all I've done is factor out the common prefixes among your choices and put them before the choice point.